# Probability to get sequence of colors when taking increasing number of balls

Tags: probability

Let's suppose I have a box with unlimited balls. Each ball is either Blue, White or Red ($1/3$ each).

If I take $3$ balls, what is the probability to get BWR in this order? And what if I take $4$ balls (knowing that I can get BWR on the first three or last three balls).

To simplify the problem, I suppose there is always $1/3$ chance to get each ball, even if we remove some. But even with that, I can't find the solution.

Is there a formula that can be written depending on the number of colors, and the number of balls taken?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw the balls one by one, you can be in one of four states after each draw: state $1$, you already got BWR; state $2$, you haven't, but the last two balls you drew were BW; state $3$, you haven't, but the last ball you drew was B; and state $4$, none of the above. The probabilities $p^i_n$ to be in state $i$ after drawing $n$ balls fulfill the following recurrences:

\begin{eqnarray*}
p^1_{n+1}&=&\frac13p^2_n+p^1_n\;,\\
p^2_{n+1}&=&\frac13p^3_n\;,\\
p^3_{n+1}&=&\frac13\left(p^2_n+p^3_n+p^4_n\right)\;,\\
p^4_{n+1}&=&\frac13\left(p_n^2+p^3_n+2p^4_n\right)\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

with initial values $p^1_0=p^2_0+p^3_0=0$ and $p^4_0=1$. These can be solved explicitly in terms of the eigenvalues of the associated matrix, but if you just want the first few values, you can just apply the recurrences by hand:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
n&p^1_n&p^2_n&p^3_n&p^4_n\\\hline
0&0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&\frac13&\frac23\\
2&0&\frac19&\frac13&\frac59\\
3&\frac1{27}&\frac19&\frac13&\frac{14}{27}\\
4&\frac2{27}&\frac19&\frac{26}{81}&\frac{40}{81}\\
5&\frac19&\frac{26}{243}&\frac{25}{81}&\frac{115}{243}\\
6&\frac{107}{729}&\frac{25}{243}&\frac8{27}&\frac{331}{729}
\end{array}
$$